# How to edit Wiki Markup more efficiently?

Tags: wiki

I'm adding a simple table into our project's wiki page and I'm just wondering whether there is way for the table to have the auto-fill capability like Excel. For ex., auto generating index for all the rows, or fill specific column a same value for all rows.

On the Rich-Text Editor of wiki I cannot do nothing except manual input, but I found this markup format and wondering if I can do some tricks there. So any other tips of of efficiently editing wiki pages will be helpful too.

EDIT: Did a little Google and looks to me this wiki markup is not standard over all wikis, but is there any common tool or script people use?

Comment: Wiki markup is just text, so being a wizard with a good text-editor makes for extremely efficient editing, even with tables. Vim, Emacs, Notepad++ I guess, etc. Perhaps not the tip you wanted, but a tip nonetheless :-) .

Comment: I see. Just want to know how wiki gurus are editing them. Thanks!

Comment: This question is on Stack Overflow, too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17161515/1591669